# Fluent NHibernate: How to perform INNER JOIN?

Tags: c#, join, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I was wondering if someone could help me. I want to perform `SQL INNER JOIN` operation by using `NHibernate`. First of all let me introduce you to the structure of my database.

[image]

I have the following parameters into my `C#` method: `int documentId`, `int userId`, `int folderId`. My main goal is to get `RoleDocumentValueEntity`. By using `USER_ID` and `FOLDER_ID` I can get the unique `FolderUserRoleEntity`. I am looking for the `ROLE_ID`. I want to join `ROLE_DOCUMENT_VALUE` and `FOLDER_USER_ROLES` tables by `ROLE_ID` where `DOCUMENT_ID` is equal to specific value which I have as a parameter of `C#` method.

**My entities:**

```
 public class RoleDocumentValueEntity
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual RoleEntity Role { get; set; }
        public virtual DocumentEntity Document { get; set; }
        public virtual string Text { get; set; }
    }

    public class RoleEntity 
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<UserRoleEntity> UserRoles { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<FolderUserRoleEntity> FolderUserRoles { get; set; }
    }

    public class FolderEntity
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual UserEntity User { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<DocumentEntity> Documents {get; set;}
    }

    public class UserEntity
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserRoleEntity
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual RoleEntity Role { get; set; }
    }

    public class FolderUserRoleEntity
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual RoleEntity Role { get; set; }
        public virtual FolderEntity Folder { get; set; }
    }
```

**Mappings:**

```
public class RoleDocumentValueMap : BaseDatabaseMap<RoleDocumentValueEntity>
    {
        public RoleDocumentValueMap()
        {
            this.Table("ROLE_DOCUMENT_VALUE");
            Id(x => x.Id, "ROLE_DOCUMENT_VALUE_ID");

            // Relationships
            References(x => x.Role)
                .Column("ROLE_ID")
                .Cascade.None();

            References(x => x.Document)
                .Column("DOCUMENT_ID")
                .Cascade.None();
        }
    }

public class RoleMap : BaseDatabaseMap<RoleEntity>
    {
        public RoleMap()
        {
            this.Table("ROLES");

            Id(x => x.Id, "ROLE_ID");

            HasMany(x => x.UserRoles)
                .KeyColumn("ROLE_ID")
                .Cascade.All()
                .Inverse();

            HasMany(x => x.FolderUserRoles)
                .KeyColumn("ROLE_ID")
                .Cascade.All()
                .Inverse();
        }
    }

public class UserRoleMap : BaseDatabaseMap<UserRoleEntity>
    {
        public UserRoleMap()
        {
            this.Table("USER_ROLES");

            this.Id(x => x.Id, "USER_ROLE_ID");
            Map(x => x.UserId).Column("USER_ID");
            References(x => x.Role).Column("ROLE_ID").Cascade.None().Fetch.Join(); 
        }
    }

public class FolderUserRoleMap : BaseDatabaseMap<FolderUserRoleEntity>
    {
        public FolderUserRoleMap()
        {
            this.Table("FOLDER_USER_ROLES");
            Id(x => x.Id, "FOLDER_USER_ROLE_ID");
            Map(x => x.UserId).Column("USER_ID");
            References(x => x.Folder).Column("FOLDER_ID").Cascade.None().Fetch.Join();
            References(x => x.Role).Column("ROLE_ID").Cascade.None().Fetch.Join().Not.LazyLoad();
        }
    }

public class FolderMap : BaseDatabaseMap<FolderEntity>
    {
        public FolderMap()
        {
            this.Table("FOLDERS");
            Id(x => x.Id, "FOLDER_ID");

            HasMany(x => x.Documents)
                .Cascade
                .AllDeleteOrphan()
                .Inverse()
                .KeyColumn("FOLDER_ID");
        }
    }

public class DocumentMap : BaseDatabaseMap<DocumentEntity>
    {
        public DocumentMap()
        {
            this.Table("DOCUMENTS");
            Id(x => x.Id, "DOCUMENT_ID");

            // Relationships
            References(x => x.Folder)
                .Column("FOLDER_ID")
                .Cascade.None();
        }
    }
```

**INNER JOIN**

I manually created SQL query which I want to get by using `NHibernate`.

```
SELECT ROLE_DOCUMENT_VALUE.*
FROM ROLE_DOCUMENT_VALUE
INNER JOIN FOLDER_USER_ROLES ON FOLDER_USER_ROLES.ROLE_ID = ROLE_DOCUMENT_VALUE.ROLE_ID
AND FOLDER_USER_ROLES.FOLDER_ID = ?
AND FOLDER_USER_ROLES.USER_ID = ?
AND ROLE_DOCUMENT_VALUE.DOCUMENT_ID = ?;
```

It looks like my `NHibernate` criteria should look like this one:

```
var result = this.Session.CreateCriteria<RoleDocumentValueEntity>()
                .CreateCriteria("FolderUserRoles", "fr")
                .Add(Restrictions.Eq("fr.UserId", userId))
                // etc
                .List();
```

But this criteria cannot be performed because `RoleDocumentValueEntity` doesn't have such property as `FolderUserRoles`.

Please, could you provide me what is the best practice in this case? How can I create the SQL query which I want by using `NHibernate`?

Answer (score 0):

you could use [linq](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querylinq.html) support for Nhibernate to achieve this easily,

```
from doc in Session.Query<RoleDocumentValueEntity>() 
join role in Session.Query<FolderUserRoleEntity>() 
on doc.Role equals role.Role
```

Comment: Yes, but will `NHibernate` caching this query? Because if you are used native SQL query and `Session.CreateSQLQuery(query)` it will execute as a new query every time. I do not know the behavior of `linq` `NHibernate`. It might affect a performance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4051546/nhibernate-linq-caching-problems answers your question in detail